# How to assign dataframe[ boolean Mask] = Series - make it row-wise ? I.e. where Mask = true take values from the same row of the Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, boolean mask (e.g. boolMask = df <= 1 ), and series of the
same vertical size as df, I want to write something like

```
df[ boolMask ] = ser
```

I.e. make an assignment of the dataframe elements where boolMask = TRUE,
and I want to make assignment row-wise i.e. assign an element from the same
row of Series to same row in DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2 ], [3, 4], [5 , 6]] ) 
ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3 ])
boolMask = df <= 1
```

Writing

```
 df[boolMask]= ser
```

causes error:
*ValueError: Must specify axis=0 or 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2 ], [3, 4], [5 , 0]] ) 
print (df)
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  0

ser = pd.Series([10, 20, 30 ])
boolMask = df <= 1

print (boolMask)
       0      1
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False   True

#replace first and second value of ser - row processing
df1 = df.mask(boolMask, ser, axis=1)
print (df1)
    0   1
0  10   2
1   3   4
2   5  20

#replace first and third value of ser - column processing
df2 = df.mask(boolMask, ser, axis=0)
print (df2)
    0   1
0  10   2
1   3   4
2   5  30
```

Comment: Thank you very very much again ! It really works ! (In my case I need axis = 0 ). I'll accept answer when it will allow me - 5 minutes ...

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774161/assign-a-series-to-all-columns-of-the-dataframe-columnwise